# Weapon damage bonuses and critical hits

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, critical-hit

1. If a player has a +1 Dagger (example), and then he score a critical hit, is the "+1" thing doubled too or just the damage dice? Will the damage be 2d4 **+1** +ability mod *or* 2d4 **+2** +ability mod?
2. If a sword deals 1d6 +2 necrotic damage, is only the "+2" necrotic or all of the damage?
3. On the 2nd question, if crits, the +2 is doubled too?

I'm trying to use only the official rules.

Comment: I suspect the answer to the second question will depend on the exact wording of the thing adding the necrotic damage; a specific example may be more useful.

Comment: A dagger enchanted with necrotic property... Something like this >< I'm newbie xD

Comment: @AliceDM is the dagger found anywhere in the DMG or PHB? Or is it a homebrewed dagger?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### 1 and 3

PHB, pg. 196

> Roll all of the attack's damage dice twice and add them together. Then add any relevant modifiers as normal.

Crits only double the dice rolled, not the modifiers. It also doubles any and all dice applied to the damage. If a spell or ability added any dice to the attack damage, you roll those twice as well. So, a +1 dagger does 2d4 + 1 damage on crit. Another example, *Eldritch Blast* hitting a target affected by *Hex* does 1d10 + 1d6 normally and 2d10 + 2d6 on crit, plus any relevant modifiers such as *Agonizing Blast*.

### 2

When damage is listed for any weapon, attack, spell, etc it applies to all of the dice and modifiers that come before the damage type. Thus, a weapon that does **1d6+2** *slashing* does all slashing. A weapon that does **1d6** *slashing* **+2** *necrotic* will do 1d6 slashing damage and 2 necrotic. If it were listed as **1d6 +2** *necrotic*, it will do all necrotic damage. Damage types are never assumed, they are explicit.

Comment: 1) So, if the damage is 1d6 slashing + 2 necrotic, the crit still 2d6 slashing +2 necrotic? Only official rules pls <3

Comment: @AliceDM that is correct. This information is in the PHB, but I don't have one with me to reference the page numbers. The index should help if you need to find it

Comment: So, the +x after the damage dice is a modifier that never doubles with crit? I get it, TY <3

Comment: @AliceDM yes, only ever the dice, no matter how many dice. so if you normally deal 2d10, you double the amount of dice to roll 4d10.

Comment: The PH page reference is 196: "*Roll all of the attack's damage dice twice and add them together. Then add any relevant modifiers as normal.*"

Answer (score -1):

1) Only the damage dice are doubled. The modifiers are not.

So in your example, a +1 dagger that crits, will deal 2d4+1+abmod damage.

2) Usually only the +2 is necrotic. The 1d6 will be normal damage type (for a sword, likely Slashing or Piercing). However, this kind of depends on what effect exactly gives the +2 necrotic damage. Certain effects may say that all of the damage becomes necrotic. These should usually mention that.

3) The +2 is *not* doubled. The sword, if it crits, will deal 2d6+2+abmod damage.

Comment: 2 is incorrect. when a damage type is given, it's given for all of the dice and numbers that preceded it. So if it said 1d6 slashing +2 necrotic, you'd be correct. But if it just says 1d6 +2 necrotic, it's all necrotic.

Comment: @PremierBromanov Please see the comment on the question that the dagger is “A dagger enchanted with necrotic property... Something like this.” The way it is written in the question is not necessarily an exact copy of what is in the book; the OP may be confused even about how it’s written. You may be right (I’m AFB and haven’t played enough 5e to remember), but *if* your comment is based purely on the text in the question, you may be misunderstanding.

Comment: So, if It's 1d6 +2 necrotic, the crit damage will be 2d6 +4 or 2d6 +2 necrotic damage instead?

Comment: @AliceDM per my and per this answer, only double dice, not modifiers.

Comment: So, 1d6 +2 necrotic will be 2d6 +2 necrotic on crit? Thanks guys :3

Comment: @AliceDM I think so, but you may want to see how other users feel about our differing answers before you decide.